# Get the nearest camera point cloud cluster with open3d

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I am getting used to Open3D library and now I get a problem with clustering point cloud data. Following are my code and image of the point cloud after being clustered. How can I get only the nearest camera part (the hand part in this scenario)?

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rd

###
# reading depth image part
###

# ===== convert numpy array to open3d image =====
image = o3d.geometry.Image(depth.astype(np.uint16))
width, height = np.asarray(image).shape
intrinsic_mat = o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(width, height, 475.065948, 475.065857, 315.944855, 245.287079)
extrinsic_mat = np.array([
                    [0.999988496304, -0.00468848412856, 0.000982563360594, 25.7], 
                    [0.00469115935266, 0.999985218048, -0.00273845880292, 1.22],
                    [-0.000969709653873, 0.00274303671904, 0.99999576807, 3.902], 
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]
                ])
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_depth_image(image, intrinsic_mat, extrinsic_mat)
## flip the pointcloud
pcd.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
## uncomment to view the point cloud
# o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

with o3d.utility.VerbosityContextManager(o3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Debug) as cm:
    labels = np.array(pcd.cluster_dbscan(eps=0.02, min_points=50, print_progress=True))

max_label = labels.max()
print(f"point cloud has {max_label + 1} clusters")
colors = plt.get_cmap("tab20")(labels / (max_label if max_label > 0 else 1))
colors[labels < 0] = 0
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors[:, :3])
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```